# Java communication with a website

Tags: java, html, chatbot

I made a simple chatbot that responds to certain prompts with string output in Java. I want this program to output it's responses to an element on an HTML based webpage, and read input from the a different element on the same page.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Here's the code if you're interested:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class botRun 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        PepperBot bot = new PepperBot();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.nextLine();

        while(true)
        {
            if(bot.shouldRespond(input))
            {
                System.out.println(bot.getRespond(input));  
            }
            input = in.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

all other methods, "shouldRespond(String x)" and getRespond(String x) are in a separate class for object "PepperBot()" and check if the bot should respond and get the appropriate response respectively.

Pretty much any solution will do, as long as it isn't costly.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a personal coding service

Comment: What have you tried so far when it comes to web based solutions? Have you had a look at any of the many java MVC frameworks to set up a web service (or web server)? I recommend [Spring MVC](http://spring.io/)

Comment: Thanks Redmega, I'll check that out, and redFive, I'm sorry if it came off like  I was asking someone to write my code for me, I just wanted to see if anyone knew of a way to do this and could point me in the right direction. I'll try to word my question better next time :)